# После сброса, отключились гугл сервис и не могу пройти начальную настройку телефона. Что делать?

Tags: android

Мой друг забрал телефон и сделал сброс настроек, но там нужно было подтвердить Гугл  аккаунт. Он через quickshortcutmaker отключил гугл сервис и перезагрузил телефон. Что после идёт вечная загрузка  по типу " ждите, проверка обновлений". Как можно обойти и убрать эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Сбрось еще раз и не юзай странный софт. Чекни есть ли в стоке гуглосервисы, если нет, установи nikgapps